# How to use ReportService2010.asmx to render a SSRS Report in ASP.NET MVC 4 App

Tags: asp.net, web-services, reporting-services

How can i use ReportService2010.asmx to render a SSRS Report in ASP.NET MVC 4 App.

I came upto adding reference to the ReportService located on my server, but dont know the how to use classes available.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that library to render a report, but you can use [ReportExecution2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.aspx) instead.